# Можно ли обратится на прямую к объекту?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

можно ли обратится к объекту по его time ?

К примеру мне нужно вывести `groupsing[0] c time = 8`

```
        groupsing: [
  [
            {time: 8, name: 'Перва группа'},
            {time: 9, name: 'Вторая группа'},,
  ],
  [
            {time: 5, name: 'Перва группа'},
            {time: 6, name: 'Вторая группа'},
            {time: 7, name: 'Третья группа'},
            {time: 8, name: 'Четвертая группа'},
            {time: 9, name: 'Пятая группа'},
  ]
        ],
```

Comment: а что мешает использовать метод [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), `groupsing.find(item => item.id === 3)` дальше делаете что хотите с найденным объектом

Comment: Смотрите, в groupsing будут несколько массивов с объектами и в каждом id могут повторятся, как мне искать именно из первого ? к примеру из groupsing[0]

Comment: отредактируйте исходный вопрос с приведением примера исходных данных и то что нужно сделать

Comment: Исправил исходный вопрос

Comment: а что надо получить, массив с элементами удовлетворяющих условию `time===8`? если да тогда как то так `groupsing.map(a => a.find(i => i.time === 8))`

Comment: Для приличия, можно и форматнуть код...

Comment: нет, к примеру искать только в первом массиве time === 8

Comment: a.find is not a function

Comment: упс, вот так надо `groupsing[0].find(e=>e.time===8);`

Comment: А можно так же как в прошлом примере с использованием map чтоб получить массив с элементами

Comment: если в исходном массиве может быть несколько элементов, то тогда вместо `find` используйте [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

Без циклов обратиться не получится, 2 цикла пройти придется если сохранится подобная вложенность.

```
   for(var i = 0; i < groupsing.length; i++){
      for(var j = 0; j < groupsing[i].length; j++){
        if(groupsing[i][j].time == 8){
          console.log(groupsing[i][j])
        }
      }
    }
```